# Massive replacing in a contentEditable DIV

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been searching about this a few days, but everything I found is with a selected text. I need to "bold" all the words within a contendEditable DIV that matches with "test".

I've been messing around getting the innerText from the DIV and change those words with the same with bold, but the cursor gets lost and when inerting again the changes with innerHTML, the cursor goes at the beginning. So I started searching doing those changes directly on the DIV, and the only thing I found its the execCommand, but at far as I know, you must select text first, and do the change, one by one. I would like to read all the DIV and make changes on the fly, is this posible? Is there a way to combine execCommand with regex?

Please, give me some light! :)

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to accomplish. Is [this](http://jsbin.com/gajibuxoso/1) of any help to you?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bold the words inside a contenteditable div, that is equivalent to placing `<strong>` tags around the given words.

So, I believe your problem could be solved with first defining a RegExp, with a 'g' flag for global

```
var boldText = "test"
var testRegEx = new RegExp(boldText, "g")
```

and then, where $div is the JQuery object representing your collection of divs (or the one) whose contents you want to modify:

```
$div.html($div.html().replace(textRegEx,"<strong>" + boldText + "</strong>"))
```